# Can’t cd to /var/www/discourse/current

Tags: capistrano, discourse

I'm following instruction [deploying-discourse-with-capistrano](http://davidcel.is/blog/2013/05/02/deploying-discourse-with-capistrano/)

When I'm doing `cap deploy:setup` I get:

```
executing "cd /var/www/discourse/current && bundle install"
 ...
 ** [out :: ...] sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /var/www/discourse/current
```

The command `cap deploy:check` says that everything is ok

What might be a problem here?

Comment: Are you running as root? Does that directory exist? If you're not root, do you have `r-x` or `rwx` permissions on it?

Comment: I think so, here's my permissions: https://gist.github.com/sevenmaxis/7186892

Comment: It doesn't look like that directory actually exists.  FWIW, I tried to follow the same steps as you and ran into many issues so I eventually just followed the steps on the Discourse github site and deployed manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
cd /var/www/discourse
./discourse-setup
```

Reference article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-discourse-on-ubuntu-16-04